# Simple cropping with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, crop

I would like to crop images on upload using Paperclip to get square thumbs from the center of the original picture. I find out a method in documentation that seems to do exactly what I want:

[transformation_to(dst, crop = false)](http://dev.thoughtbot.com/paperclip/classes/Paperclip/Geometry.html)

The problem is that I can't figure out where to use this method. It would be great to simply pass something as a parameter here:

```
  has_attached_file :picture, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "600x600>", :thumb => "something here" }
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You only need to use # instead of > as a parameter:

```
has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :thumb => "200x200#" }
```

Comment: The # is paperclip specific. Paperclip uses it as a marker to center and crop the image. You can look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb for more.

Comment: Paperclip documentation about resizing and cropping options here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation#resizing-options